# How does Rust compiler decide how much memory it should allocate for an enum value?

Tags: enums, rust

While I was reading [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-01-box.html#computing-the-size-of-a-non-recursive-type), I came across the statement (emphasis mine):

> To determine how much space to allocate for a `Message` value, Rust goes through each of the variants to see which variant needs the most space. Rust sees that `Message::Quit` doesn’t need any space, `Message::Move` needs enough space to store two `i32` values, and so forth. **Because only one variant will be used, the most space a `Message` value will need is the space it would take to store the largest of its variants.**

The `Message` enum is defined as:

```rust
enum Message {
    Quit,
    Move { x: i32, y: i32 },
    Write(String),
    ChangeColor(i32, i32, i32),
}
```

What does the bold statement mean in detail?

Comment: It does the same thing as any other language supporting discriminated unions, that is: calculate the memory requirement for each alternative, pick the largest value, add fixed overhead for discriminant.

Comment: Fixed overhead for discriminant? What does this mean?

Comment: Let's say you construct your message using a string. How does the receiver of your message knows it's a string and not a number tuple (that is, option 3 rather than any other option)?

Comment: I understand now, it's like a metadata. You can write down answer.